# Flutter StreamBuilder not listening to new data?

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I have two screens, one where the user can chat with a particular person and the second screen, where he can see a list of all the chats.

The aim is to display the last message on the second screen. This is done as follows:

1. The user sends/receives a new message?
2. Update the database
3. BloC sends a new stream of data by fetching the newest data.

The problem is, the stream builder isn't listening to the new data (not sure why). To the best of my knowledge, the BloC is sending a new stream of data when the user sends a message, it just doesn't re-render in the list.

Here's a shortened version of the code:

```
class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
final ContactsBloc _contactsBloc = ContactsBloc();

@override()
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, true);
              },
            ),
            body: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                   child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                          message = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                   ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                   onPressed: () async {
                      //update remote and local databases
                      await _contactsBloc.updateContact(
        {'last_message': utf8.decode(base64.decode(message))},
        'conversation_id = ?',
        [conversationId]);
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Send',
                          style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

The chats screen:

```
class ChatsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const id = 'chats';

  @override
  _ChatsScreenState createState() => _ChatsScreenState();
}

class _ChatsScreenState extends State<ChatsScreen> {
  final ContactsBloc _contactsBloc = ContactsBloc();
  Iterable<Contact> contacts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chats'),
      body: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _contactsBloc.contacts,
        builder: (context, results) {
          print('New stream: $results');
          if (!results.hasData) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            List contacts = results.data;
            contacts = contacts
                .where((element) => element.lastMessage != null)
                .toList();
            if (contacts.length > 0) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: contacts.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  ContactModel contact = contacts[index];
                  return ChatItem(
                    name: contact.name,
                    message: contact.lastMessage,
                    profilePicture: contact.profilePictureUrl,
                    lastSeen: contact.lastSeen,
                    user: currentUser,
                    toUser: contact.uid,
                    conversationId: contact.conversationId,
                  );
                },
              );
            }
            return Container();
          }
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

The contact BloC:

```
class ContactsBloc {
  ContactsBloc() {
    getAllContacts();
  }

  final _contactsController = StreamController<List<ContactModel>>.broadcast();
  Stream<List<ContactModel>> get contacts => _contactsController.stream;

  _dispose() {
    _contactsController.close();
  }

  getAllContacts() async {
    List<ContactModel> contacts = await DatabaseProvider.db.getAllContacts();
    _contactsController.sink.add(contacts);
  }


  updateContact(var update, String where, List whereArgs) async {
    await DatabaseProvider.db.updateContact(update, where, whereArgs);
    getAllContacts();
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure they're the same instance of ContactBloc in ChatScreen and ChatsScreen, as far as I can tell they're different so sinking data in one won't update in the other, try make it a Singleton of ContactBloc

Comment: I suspected this to be the problem and in fact I guess this still..but I have no idea how to implement a singleton pattern. Could you throw light on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now try adding this to create a Singleton instance of `ContactBloc`

```
class ContactsBloc{
  ContactsBloc._();
  static final ContactsBloc _instance = ContactsBloc._();
  factory ContactsBloc() => _instance;

 /// the rest of your code...
 
}
```

I would recommend checking some state management if you want more control of your classes (Bloc, Provider, Redux, etc)

Comment: What does ContactsBloc._(); mean?

Comment: It's a named private constructor to avoid being called outside the class/file, that way calling ContactsBloc() will return always the same instance of a constructor that cannot be called outside the class